# java.sql.SQLException:ORA -01000:maximum open cursors exceeded in JAVA

Tags: java, sql, oracle, resultset, executequery

I am getting this error when I run my code

Below is the code I have used:

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE PERSONJOB='ADMIN'";
Statement stmt=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
try
{
    stmt=conn.createStatement();
    rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    While(rs.next())
    {
        String name=rs.getString(1);
        long id=rs.getLong(2);
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(id);
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}
finally
{
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
}
```

I want to reuse the connection, so I didn't close the connection.
After I closed the `ResultSet` and `Statement`, I am getting the "maximum open cursors exceeded" error.
Anyone please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `close()` of your `ResultSet` is failing, which would result in multiple open cursors and eventually hit the max configured open cursor count. Could you modify your code to:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
try 
{
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE PERSONJOB = 'ADMIN'");
  try 
  {
    while ( rs.next() ) 
    {
      String name = rs.getString(1);
      long   id   = rs.getLong(2);
      System.out.println(name);
      System.out.println(id);
    }
  } 
  finally 
  {
    try 
    { 
      rs.close(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception ignore) { }
  }
} 
finally 
{
  try 
  { 
    stmt.close(); 
  } 
  catch (Exception ignore) { }
}
```

**EDIT**: will be good to also clean up the already opened cursors with a combination of:

```
 SELECT oc.user_name, oc.sql_text, s.SID, s.SERIAL#
   FROM v$open_cursor oc
      , v$session     s
  WHERE oc.sid = s.sid
    
 EXEC SYS.KILL_SESSION(xxx,xxxxx);
```

or restart the DB.

Comment: I have tried this code also but still it is throwing the same error

Comment: Have you closed the already open cursors in the DB or restarted the DB?

Comment: No I didn't do anything in the DB.

Comment: I don't have an access to process in the DB. Is there any way to overcome from this issue in the code itself?

Comment: Don't think so, if it's different sessions that just remain hanging there might be a script that closes idle sessions, but you can't count on such.

Comment: Are sessions still up?

Comment: Yeah finally it is working .Missed to put try . After modified the code it is working. Thank you

Comment: You can mark as accepted answer so people will know it's of any use.